# Shell script to count no of character,word,line in a file

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
character=0
word=0
line=`echo -e "\n"`
space=`echo -e " "`


if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "You haven't entered any line"
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    filename=$1
    while read -n1 newline
    do
        if [ '$newline' == '$line' ]
        then
            ((line++))
        elif [ '$newline' == '$space' ]
        then
            ((word++))
        else
            ((character++))
        fi
    done < $filename
    echo "No of line =$line"
    echo "No of word =$word"
    echo "No of character =$character"
fi
```

Comment: I am not getting desire output .Anyone can help!

Comment: Why not use `wc(1)` directly? It's part of Core Utilities and should be available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Double** quotes around a variable are OK, but don't put **single** quotes around each variable as was done here:

```
    if [ '$newline' == '$line' ]
```

To see why that fails, look at the following code, where the pale blue text is code, and the pink text is output:

```
a=3 
echo $a
```

> 3

```
echo '$a'
```

> $a

```
if [ '$a' == 3 ] ; then echo true ; else echo false ; fi
```

> false

```
if [ $a == 3 ] ; then echo true ; else echo false ; fi
```

> true

Comment: @iBug, Interesting -- usually I quote things in a `Code:<cr>`, *the code<cr>*, `Output:`, *the output* format.  Colors seemed simpler here.  I'd be curious to see what evidence exists that the *SE* blue code and pink text colors are in fact difficult to distinguish for the colorblind.

Comment: @iBug, [This *meta* Q](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325705/black-green-blue-and-light-blue-are-pretty-colorblind-unfriendly-choice-for-co) seems to corroborate that this might indeed be a problem for some.

Comment: @iBug, Thanks, but I understood your meaning the first time.  The *meta* link was in reference to the general problems of colorblind coders, rather than your preference of [RGB hex triplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Shorthand_hexadecimal_form) in place of English color names.

Comment: can u please correct my code ,its not working even i am not using single code around variable.It should count first character,word then line.

Comment: @uttam, Please edit your question, and then show the newly modified code, and the output when you run it.

Comment: @uttam, Please don't put that in a comment, instead re-edit your question, and include and newly modified code, and the output.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of what single quotes do? It **prevents *any* escaping, or string substitution from occurring**. In other words, it denotes **raw string** (you can't even put a single quote inside a single quote!).

You should change to double quotes if you want variable expansion inside:

```sh
if [ "$newline" == "$line" ]
#    ^        ^    ^     ^
```

Comment: Maybe this answer is too similar to [a prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47729237/6136214)?

Comment: @agc Not *too* silimar. The explanation is written on my own. I voted you up, satisfy.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

WC=$(cat $1 | wc -mlw)

echo "No of line =$(echo $WC | awk '{print $1}')"
echo "No of word =$(echo $WC | awk '{print $2}')"
echo "No of character =$(echo $WC | awk '{print $3}')"
```

Comment: This is more efficient than calling awk three times: `read lines words chars < <(wc -lwm "$1")`. Don't forget to [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: There seems to some confusion as to whether the OP wanted pure `bash` or *shell* code, (*i.e.* was in need of help with an exercise), rather than to use an existing tool.

Comment: Don't use uppercase for your variables. Don't `cat` a single file. Quote your variables.  This could be replaced with `set -- $(wc <"$1")` (chars in `$1`, words in `$2`, lines in `$3`).

Comment: what's the reason for down votes? it solves the OP's question even if its not the most efficient solution